# Stacking skewed divs with background images

Tags: html, css

I'm working with skewed divs and have an issue with how to deal with stacking/overlaps.

I have 3 divs; 
- Div1 has a simple background color and is not skewed
- Div2 is skewed at the top and has a background image (background color set to the same as Div1)
- Div3 is a repeat of div2 with a different background image.

Trouble is, the skewed part of div3 has div1 background color - i want it to show the background image of div2.

Does that make sense?

[This is what it looks like right now - i want to get rid of the red and show the image instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcvMN.png)

Thanks!

**HTML & CSS**

```css
/* 8. Sections */
    section {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
      }
      
      /* Homepage - Hero */
      section.hero {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #E2004B;
      }
      
      /* Homepage - VWEAR */
      section.vwear {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100vw;
        background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1oaThTzD6dpXolbB0OSxDMMTC52VF1A0f");
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
      }
      
      section.vwear:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        bottom: 100%;
        left: 0;
        transform: skewY(-3deg);
        transform-origin: right;
        background: #E2004B;
      }
      
      /* Homepage - VGEAR */
      section.vgear {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100vw;
        background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1-WIqMPtFY1I6WyDYFnSyhvkYqVNqdR9o");
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
      }
      
      section.vgear:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        bottom: 100%;
        left: 0;
        transform: skewY(-3deg);
        transform-origin: right;
        background: #E2004B;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stacking_div_skew.css">
</head>
<body>
    HTML
<!-- start Hero Section-->
    <section class="hero" data-section-name="hero" id="hero">
        <div class="txt-container">
            <div class="hero-txt">BIG HEADLINE TEXT<br><br>SMALLER SUBTITLE</div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- end Hero Section -->

    <!-- start V:WEAR Section-->
    <section class="vwear" data-section-name="vwear" id="vwear">
      <div class="txt-container">
        <div class="hero-txt">BIG HEADLINE TEXT<br><br>SMALLER SUBTITLE</div></div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- end V:WEAR Section -->

    <!-- start V:GEAR Section-->
    <section class="vgear" data-section-name="vgear" id="vgear">
      <div class="txt-container">
        <div class="hero-txt">BIG HEADLINE TEXT<br><br>SMALLER SUBTITLE</div></div>
      </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhVQp.png)

Comment: are div2 and div 3 inside div1 ?

Comment: no - the divs are stacked in sections

Comment: share your HTML and CSS here

Comment: added the html and css

Comment: yes, that's right since I duplicated the css and added a background image to div2 and div3.

Comment: just use `background-image: url("../img/hero-vwear.png")` for `section.vgear:before` selector instead of `background: #E2004B;` .

Comment: kinda works, but the images don't align...

Comment: uploaded a screen grab...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to achieve something like the following:

```css
section {
  padding: 25px 20px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
margin-top: -10px;
  clip-path: polygon( 0 10px, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

section:nth-child(3) {
margin-top: -10px;
  clip-path: polygon( 0 0, 100% 10px, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<section class="red">Top</section>
<section class="green">Middle</section>
<section class="blue">Bottom</section>
```

I'd personally go with this method as its clean and easy to implement. You apply a clip path to angle the top edge and then use a negative margin to pull that element on top of the element before it. You can add extra padding to the elements which are overlapped to ensure content is not covered.

Comment: Thanks James. I was under the impression that Clip Path is not a widely supported feature as yes, right?

Comment: With `-webkit-` flags support isn't bad. You'd just be missing out on IE/Edge really. It depends on if this is a vital feature for you or whether it can be progressive enhancement.